# make certain text from sms able to pop up copy option on android

Tags: java, android, sms, smslib

I send sms using java with smslib library, that contain code that i want to copy when sms received from my android device.

here is my code

```
String stringMessage = "code : xxxxxxyyyyyzzzzzz \n"
                            + "any question : http:/sitamvan.com";

String number = "08888888888";

OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(number, stringMessage);
Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
```

for example the text on the sms will be like this

code : xxxxxxyyyyyzzzzzz 
any question : http:/sitamvan.com

when i received the sms (i opened it with default sms app), the url is blue in color and can be copied just by tap on it and the copy option will be popped up.

is it possible to make my code blue in color too? so the default sms app read my code as some copyable text just like when number or link is present on it? may be by adding some text or enclose it with apostrophe?

Comment: automatically read that sms in your app

Comment: i'm not building an app actually, i just want default sms app read my code as some copyable text just like when number or link is present on it.

Comment: Can you please paste your code of sending sms.

Comment: ok wait i will update my question

Comment: i already update it